# iMacros - Open an iFrame in another tab

Tags: iframe, embed, imacros

How could I open an iFrame in a new tab? I tried using **URLCURRENT** after selecting the iFrame with **"FRAME F = 1"** but it did not work.

I think this could be done by using "**SEARCH**" to search the iFrame code and extract the URL, but I do not know how to do it.

---

iMacros Firefox (Version 8.9.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go...

```
  'Clear Extraction memory
SET !EXTRACT NULL
  'Using current tab/window
TAB T=1 
  'Extract URL from first IFrame
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IFRAME ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF  
  'Pass URL to variable
SET iFrameURL {{!EXTRACT}} 
  'Open new Tab/window
TAB OPEN
  'Switch to the new Tab/window 
TAB T=2 
  'Navigate to URL from varable (iframe url)
URL GOTO={{iFrameURL}}
```

Modify the `POS=1` to the appropriate iframe location if there are multiple iframe... so `POS=3` for the 3rd iFrame.

Please mark this as an answer if this solution helped you.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much!
I did not know that "iframe" could be used as "Type". It works perfectly :)